# Ignore the last object in array in PHP

Tags: php

I have this little code here :

```
$arrayName = array('0','1','2');
foreach ($arrayName as $key) {
    echo $key . ',';
}
```

So now the Output is this :

> > 0,1,2,

If i want to have this what should i do ? :

> > 0,1,2

I mean not inserting "," for last object in an array .

thanks .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can either use [join](http://php.net/function.join%E2%80%8E) or [implode](http://www.php.net/implode)

```
echo join(',', $arrayName);
```

OR

```
echo implode(',', $arrayName);
```

Comment: Tell me, were you inspired by the other two answers when you were writing this?

Comment: @JanDvorak: `implode` came to my mind at once, and `join`, of course inspired :)

Comment: @JanDvorak Glad to see that _"fastest answer in the West"_ principle is failing sometimes (well, not glad to see that it was on my answer)

Comment: @AlmaDo, That is correct , people upvoted this answer by seeing the reps difference I guess , However you got mine already one the first place.

Comment: why the output is this ?! `0,1,20,1,20,1,2`

Comment: @user3394468: you dont have to use both the code. **either implode or join**

Comment: @user3394468 because outputting two times. Use one way (like in.. well, "missed" answers below)

Comment: @AlmaDo i am using 1 way now (implode) `echo implode(',',$arrayName);`

Answer (score 3):

Do this way:

```
echo join(',', $arrayName);
```

You should **not** use loop with this (i.e. place this *instead* of loop, not *inside* loop)

Answer (score 2):

Try to **[implode](https://www.php.net/implode)** them like

```
$arrayName = array('0','1','2');
echo implode(',',$arrayName);
```

Comment: why the output is this ?! `0,1,20,1,20,1,2`

Comment: Either you use `Join` or `Implode` at once...both gives your desired OP.

Comment: I am using this : `$arrayName = array('0','1','2');foreach ($arrayName as $key) {echo implode(',',$arrayName);}` but still the output is not correct

Comment: You dont need to put this in loop.First remove your foreach loop and try the single statement.As like my edit